# Quadruple precision float support on Intel C++ compiler 18.0 update 3 in vs 2017

Tags: c++, intel, quadruple-precision

I just tried to compile a C++ program with `boost::multiprecision::float128` support in Visual Studio 2017 using Intel C++ compiler 18.0 update 3.

I add `/Qoption,cpp,--extended_float_type` to project C/C++ additional options.

However, ICC emit `E0020: identifier "_Quad" is undefined` error message.

I searched the latest ICC 18 Developer Guide and Reference relating to quadruple precision float and _Quad topics and couldn't find anything.

Is `_Quad` keyword still supported in ICC 18, or I made mistakes in compiler options? 
Thanks.

- OS: Windows 10 x64 1803
- Visual studio 2017 15.7.3
- Intel C++ compiler 18.0 update 3

Comment: From https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html , have you tried defining `BOOST_MP_USE_QUAD`?

Comment: Yes, I did. Even the test program in boost::multiprecision::float128 doc will get the same error in icc 18, while it is completely fine in gcc with -lquadmath option.